# Docker, aufs, and unattended-upgrades

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I'm running Docker on Ubuntu 16.04 with unattended-upgrades configured. Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't come with the aufs storage driver by default so I have to install it manually with `` apt-get install linux-image-extra-`uname -r `` `.

Since I have unattended-upgrades configured, sometimes the kernel gets upgraded. When it does, I lose the linux-image-extra package. After a reboot, docker stops working since aufs is not available.

My question is: How do I configure unattended-upgrades to also upgrade/install linux-image-extra?

More info:

```
# /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades

Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
     "origin=Ubuntu,archive=${distro_codename}-security,label=Ubuntu";
  };

Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
};
```